# Using <p> tags why has oversight here become so petty, self righteous, anal, unforgiving & passive aggressive? It's a code forum. BTW -1

Tags: javascript, html, select, dropdown

How do I capture the option Label (not Value) from a select dropdown and create a h1 heading when the option is selected. I also need to ignore the "Please Choose" selection? The heading should only be created if an option is selected (other than Please Choose).Thanks

```
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="" selected>Please Choose</option> 
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I need `<h1>Audi</h1>` not `<h1>audi</h1>`

Comment: please add the code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for me:

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Please Choose</option> 
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<h1 id="carSelected"></h1>
```

and

```
//target the element
var sel = document.querySelector('#cars');

//attach the event
sel.addEventListener('change', function(){
  //get and set the value
 if (document.getElementById('cars').value != ""){ 
  document.querySelector('#carSelected').textContent = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
  }
});

// execute the event on page load
var event = new Event('change');
sel.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Thanks all for your help in helping me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this? This snippet will update the value of `#display` when `#cars` changes

```js
document
  .querySelector("#cars")
  .addEventListener("change", event =>
      document
        .querySelector("#display")
        .innerText = event.target.value
  )
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<h1 id="display">place user selected option value here e.g. Audi</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

```
function manageSelect() {
 document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = document.getElementById('cars').value;
}



 <select name="cars" id="cars" onchange="manageSelect()">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<h1 id='heading'>°place user selected option label here e.g. Audi*</h1>
```

https://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer. you could add disable attribute on the 'Please Choose' option to prevent user revert the option

```js
document
  .querySelector("#cars")
  .addEventListener("change", event =>
      document
        .querySelector("#display")
        .innerText = event.target.value
  )
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please Choose</option> 
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<h1 id="display">place user selected option value here e.g. Audi</h1>
```

Comment: Oh cool. Only issue is I need the Label not the Value. I need Audi not audi and so on, Thank You! Mamun's answer above outputs Label but this outputs value: Mamun : https://jsfiddle.net/hcanning2012/8wmeof2L/1/